# URL Paramters carried between pages - how to stop tel: also?

Tags: javascript, wordpress

I have this really basic script that changes all the links on my wordpress site to preserve the url param - I use it on wordpress landing pages for my business

```
    var queryString = new URL(window.location).search;
document.querySelectorAll("[href]").forEach(link => {
    var current = link.href;
    link.href = current + queryString;
});
```

E.g.

```
website.com/?location=Australia
```

All links on the page will carry over the parameter to whatever href link my visitor clicks

```
/book-online/?location=Australia

/request-a-callback/?location=Australia
```

However this is obviously changing all my href links, and is changing my tel: links with it.

Is there a way I can make it only change https://?

My tel: links look like this

```
tel:0293 12329?location=Australia
```

I have had this code copied and pasted for ages, I know absolutely nothing about javascript and no idea where I found the above code, I've just used it for ages and it works as a quick and easy way for me to track a users progress through my landing pages.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could only do this if `tel:` is not in the href?

```js
var queryString = new URL(window.location).search;
document.querySelectorAll("[href]").forEach(link => {
  var current = link.href;
  if (!current.includes("tel:")) {
    link.href = current + queryString;
  }
});
```